# Generate HmacSHA256 based on groovy code into Python

Tags: python

I was given some code in groovy and asked to convert it to Python.

```
def generateHmac(String data){
        String secretKey = '123445667777'
        byte[] digest

        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256")
        mac.init(secretKeySpec)
        digest = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes())
        
        //we use hex encoding for our tokens.
        String token = digest.encodeHex().toString()

        return token
    }
```

I have tried many times but failed:

```
def generateHmac(String data):
    data = "my_url"
    secret_key = b"123445667777"

    h = SHA256.new()
    h.update(secret_key)
    h.update(b"data")
    print(h.hexdigest())
```

Comment: What exactly is  the problem with the Python code you have written? Besides `String data` should just be `data`.

Comment: SHA256 != HMAC-SHA, so that’s one thing.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC

Comment: Hmac use this secret key to generate two keys that will get hashed later with the message to prevent length extension attacks. It generate these two by x-oring secret key with inner and outer padding separately so it's not the secret key that get involved directly with HASH generation.

Answer (score 1):

An hmac is not the same thing as a digest.  HmacSHA26 uses SHA256, it isn't the same thing as SHA256.  You need to use the [hmac library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html) to get the correct result.

```
hmac.digest(secretKey, message, "Sha256")
```

should give you what you want, with the `secretKey` and `message` being bytes.

The above is equivalent to the longer form:

```
hmac.new(secretKey, message, "Sha256").digest()
```

but once you have the hmac object, you can other things like `update()` with more text or `hexdigest()` to get a text-like digest.

Comment: Thank you guys so much, because of your help and insights I was able to resolve my issue with:

h = hmac.new(secret_key, msg=bytes(key_url, 'utf-8'), digestmod="SHA256")
token = h.hexdigest()